# Angular2: Pass boolean through routerLink

Tags: html, angular, routes

I'm trying to pass a a boolean through a routerLink from a task-page to a team-page but I can't seem to use the value in my HTML-sheet, am I doing something wrong?

*I've tried to do it like this*:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/team', projectID, {projectTeam: true}]">Teampage</a>
```

*and I've tried to do it like this*:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/team', projectID" [queryParams]="{projectTeam: true}>Teampage</a>
```

However no error is shown and there is no issue compiling, neither of them seem to work and I can't use @Input() because its a link `<a>` tag.

*The HTML-sheet where I want to use the boolean*:

```
<md-card>
   <md-card-title *ngIf="projectTeam" class="card_title_center">Project</md-card-title>
   <md-card-subtitle class="card_title_center">TEAM</md-card-subtitle>
   ...
</md-card>
```

Used documentation: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RouterLink-directive.html

Comment: Where do you assign `projectTeam` in your component?

Comment: @echonax When using @Input(), I would declare the projectTeam boolean in the typescript file of the place where I want to use it. However, I didn't specify it while passing it through the routerLink, is this necessary for it to work? I already am putting the value in the routerLink right?

Comment: md-card-title element needs `this.projectTeam` in your component. If it's undefined..

Comment: I defined it and still got no result

Comment: Did you assign it to anything?

Comment: I assigned it in the routerLink, like this: <a [routerLink]="['/team', projectID, {projectTeam: true}]">Teampage</a>, defined it in the team-detail.ts like this: projectTeam: boolean; which I used in the HTML-file like this: <md-card-title *ngIf="this.projectTeam" class="card_title_center">Project</md-card-title>

Comment: That's not assigning. You are just giving the router a parameter. You need to subscribe to router params and assign the result to something. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#activatedroute-the-one-stop-shop-for-route-information

Comment: That solved it, can you post that as an answer so I can accept it? What I've added in the team-detail.ts after follwing your documentation was - import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router'; export class TeamDetailComponent { projectTeam: string;

  constructor(private _routeParams: ActivatedRoute) {
        this.projectTeam = _routeParams.snapshot.params['projectTeam'];
  }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comment section,

You need to assign the query parameter inside your component

Example:

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

...
export class TeamDetailComponent { 

  projectTeam: string; 

  constructor(private _routeParams: ActivatedRoute) { 
    this.projectTeam = _routeParams.snapshot.params['projectTeam']; 
  }

}
```

Comment: I may have spoken too soon. you're correct in the fact that I didn't assigned my parameter but when testing this solution, I watched an old result. Therefore your solution is correct, but I still can't get it to work. Anything else I might have done wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by old result?

Comment: Right now you are using the example in `SNAPSHOT: THE NO-OBSERVABLE ALTERNATIVE` section. But if you are going to reuse this component, you may need to do it like the switchMap example and subscribe to `this._routeParams.params`

Comment: I was watching the result while I still had a hard coded boolean in my file from when I was testing BUT.. and this is a bit awkward, I fixed the problem. I wrote *ngIf="projectTeam==true" instead of *ngIf="projectTeam=='true'" by accident. So everything works now and I can't thank you enough.

Comment: @WouterVanherck ah glad you figured it out :-)

Answer (score 0):

Params should be only in string.So try to assign the param only in string. Why don't you try this?

```
<a [routerLink]="['/team', '1']">Teampage</a>
```

(or)

```
<a [routerLink]="['/team, projectID']" [queryParams]="{[projectTeam: string]: true}">Teampage</a>
```

Comment: Don't really know what I should say about your first suggestions because I don't know where the variables dissapear to. But if it can only pass strings and I use your second suggestion, I'm getting an error. (you forgot to close your quotation mark). Want me to post the error?

Comment: For the first suggestion you can use the routing like this   { path: 'team/:id', component: TeamComponent },

Comment: For the second suggestion you  can use the routing like this { path: 'team', component: TeamComponent }   <a [routerLink]="['/team']" [queryParams]="{[projectTeam: string]: true}">Teampage</a>